# Can I add arguments to python code when I submit spark job?

Tags: python, apache-spark, cluster-mode

I'm trying to use `spark-submit` to execute my python code in spark cluster.

Generally we run `spark-submit` with python code like below.

```
# Run a Python application on a cluster
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  my_python_code.py \
  1000
```

But I wanna run `my_python_code.py`by passing several arguments Is there smart way to pass arguments?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Yes**:  Put this in a file called args.py

```
#import sys
print sys.argv
```

If you run

```
spark-submit args.py a b c d e
```

You will see:

```
['/spark/args.py', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 59):

Even though `sys.argv` is a good solution, I still prefer this more proper way of handling line command args in my PySpark jobs:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--ngrams", help="some useful description.")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.ngrams:
    ngrams = args.ngrams
```

This way, you can launch your job as follows:

```
spark-submit job.py --ngrams 3
```

More information about `argparse` module can be found in [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Comment: Not working! Results says " [TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--ngrams' "

Comment: If you have configs you want to send with your spark submit job, make sure to run with config info right after spark-submit, like: `spark-submit --master somemasterurl job.py --ngrams 3`

Comment: Haven't tried this solution but this sounds a better one because it can remove the dependency on argument sequence.

Comment: Has anybody figured how to use Pyspark with argparse? I'm continually getting an error  `Unrecognized flag --arg1` and it's driving me insane! (Spark 2.4.4 and Python 3.6)

Comment: i have a whole json of parameters that I need to pass. Is there a simple way of getting that embedded in the spark submit command?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the arguments from the spark-submit command and then access them in your code in the following way,

sys.argv[1] will get you the first argument, sys.argv[2] the second argument and so on. Refer to the below example,

You can create code as below to take the arguments which you will be passing in the spark-submit command,

```
import os
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])
a = 2
tables = []
for _ in range(n):
    tables.append(sys.argv[a])
    a += 1
print(tables)
```

Save the above file as PysparkArg.py and execute the below spark-submit command,

```
spark-submit PysparkArg.py 3 table1 table2 table3
```

Output:

```
['table1', 'table2', 'table3']
```

This piece of code can be used in PySpark jobs where it is required to fetch multiple tables from the database and, the number of tables to be fetched & the table names will be given by the user while executing the spark-submit command.

Answer (score 2):

Aniket Kulkarni's `spark-submit args.py a b c d e` seems to suffice, but it's worth mentioning we had issues with optional/named args (e.g --param1).

It appears that double dashes `--` will help signal that python optional args follow:

```
spark-submit --sparkarg xxx yourscript.py -- --scriptarg 1 arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it's possible. http://caen.github.io/hadoop/user-spark.html

```
spark-submit \
    --master yarn-client \   # Run this as a Hadoop job
    --queue <your_queue> \   # Run on your_queue
    --num-executors 10 \     # Run with a certain number of executors, for example 10
    --executor-memory 12g \  # Specify each executor's memory, for example 12GB
    --executor-cores 2 \     # Specify each executor's amount of CPUs, for example 2
    job.py ngrams/input ngrams/output
```

Comment: I think the question is not how to pass them in but rather how to access the arguments once they where passed in