# Import Airflow variable to PySpark

Tags: pyspark, airflow

lately I have been playing around with Airflow and PySpark. I saw that Airflow has a number of variables. My aim is to parse one of those variables and import it to my pySpark script. So far I tried to echo the value of the variable (worked) but then, I couldn't find a way to import in to pySpark(I want to pass the value of that variable to another variable in my pyspark script). I also attach my code( `job_id` is the variable I am talking about).

```
test_bash = """
export un_id={{ti.job_id}}
echo $un_id
"""

bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='test',
    bash_command=test_bash,
    xcom_push=True,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    rt = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='test')
    print(rt)

pull_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pull_task',
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

#############
bash_task >> pull_task
```

Any idea how should I carry on or if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is actually called `run_id` and can be accessed via the context or macros.

In the `Pythonoperator` this is accessed via context, and in the `BashOperator` this is accessed via jinja templating on the `bash_command` field.

More info on what's available in macros:

https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#macros

More info on jinja:

https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#jinja-templating

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='run_id',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2017, 2, 26)
)

def my_func(**kwargs):
    context = kwargs
    print(context['dag_run'].run_id)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_run_id',
    python_callable=my_func,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
    )

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_run_id',
    bash_command='echo {{run_id}}',
    dag=dag)

t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

Use this dag as an example, and check the log for each operator, you should see the `run_id` printed in the log.

Comment: Thank you it is working! One more thing I would like to ask you, in order to retrieve the `run_id` in my pySpark script, do I have to follow the procedure as if I was importing a system variable? Or is there a special way of retrieving and referencing to that variable?

Comment: Glad it helped, can you accept the answer so that future users who stumble upon this question know it :)

Regarding impoting `run_id` in PySpark script, depends on the operator you use to run. If you use `BashOperator`, you can use it in the same way using `{{ run_id }}` in your script

Comment: I am still struggling with the importing. I assumed that it would be an env variable but apparently it is not. I also tried this I found in the links you provided: 

`testing = "{{run_id}}"

bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_run_id',
    #bash_command='echo {{run_id}}',
    bash_command= 'tmp/myfile.py',
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
    env = {'UNIQUE_ID': testing})`
but it also did not work. I cannot understand what am I missing.

Comment: Hey no, you should use `PythonOperator` to run that file and then it would work. If you want to use BashOperator, you need to use a bash script for e.g `bash_command=run_pyspark.sh`. And your `run_pyspark.sh`, can have the first line as `export RUNID={{run_id}}; python tmp/myfile.py` and in your python file you can use this via `os.environ[RUNID]`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried what @kaxil suggested but if I understood correct your question you want ton retrieve the `run_id` variable from Airflow and use it in your python (pySpark) script. If that's the case, I assume that you use a `BashOperator` to `spark-submit` your job. When submitting a spark-job you are allowed to submit (along with your job) [some arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217160/can-i-add-arguments-to-python-code-when-i-submit-spark-job). Those arguments appear as system arguments which you can see if you do a `print(sys.argv)` (useful to see in which position is your variable). 
Since you already pushed the variable with the `bash_task` you will have to pull it. So when you submit your spark job you should also add an extra argument like this :

```
cmd=""spark-submit your-pyspark-file.py {{ ti.xcom_pull("test") }}

retrieval = BashOperator(
    namespace='randomname',
    arguments=[cmd],
    name='example-dag1',
    task_id='name-you-desire',
    provide_context=True,
    get_logs=True, 
    dag=dag)
```

Then, if you did execute the `print(sys.argv)` you will be able to see your variable as an argument and in your script you can refer to that variable by `sys.argv[1]` (if it is in the second position, 0 if it is in the first etc).