# How to trigger google dataproc job using airflow and pass parameter as well

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

As a part of a DAG, I am triggering gcp pyspark dataproc job using below code,

```
   dag=dag,
   gcp_conn_id=gcp_conn_id,
   region=region,
   main=pyspark_script_location_gcs,
   task_id='pyspark_job_1_submit',
   cluster_name=cluster_name,
   job_name="job_1"
)
```

How can I pass a variable as parameter to pyspark job that can be accessible in script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the paramter `arguments` of [DataProcPySparkOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator):

> **arguments** (list) – Arguments for the job. (templated)

```
job = DataProcPySparkOperator(
    gcp_conn_id=gcp_conn_id,
    region=region,
    main=pyspark_script_location_gcs,
    task_id='pyspark_job_1_submit',
    cluster_name=cluster_name,
    job_name="job_1",
    arguments=[
        "-arg1=arg1_value", # or just "arg1_value" for non named args
        "-arg2=arg2_value"
    ],
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: i've a string variable to pass.. so what should be format here ?
and in spark script how can i access it ?

Comment: @j' If you have one variable to passe, just use `arguments=[string_var]` in the operator. To get the variable in pyspark main job, you can use `sys.argv` or better use `argparse` package. you can see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217160/can-i-add-arguments-to-python-code-when-i-submit-spark-job) on how to pass python args