# Passing arguments to Python file that is run by PySpark

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028919/how-to-run-a-script-in-pyspark) showed how to run Python script file with `pyspark`. Particularly, this is the command I am using:

```
% pyspark < script.py
```

I want to pass an argument (a config file) to this `script.py`. Normally, running with Python alone, this would work:

```
% python script.py conf.ini
```

But with `pyspark`:

```
% pyspark < script.py conf.ini
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: pyspark does not support any application options.
```

Is it possible to do this execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add arguments to python code when I submit spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217160/can-i-add-arguments-to-python-code-when-i-submit-spark-job)

Comment: Thanks, using ```spark-submit``` works for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this to get it off the unanswered queue.
Use `spark-submit`in combination with `sys.argv` to get the input:

```
spark-submit script.py conf.ini
```